# VBA EXCEL - Extract a copy of workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to extract a copy of my workbook to a new file in VBA but I'm getting an "Application or object defined error" and i have no clue whats wrong.

All im using is the command i found on the microsoft site?

```
Public Function EWbtn()

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\CRC Chart Extract.XLS"

End Function
```

Im very confused :L

Comment: It depends on what version of Excel you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michal said, the easier way is just create the file first then populate it with your current active workbook. Here is a sample that should be able to get you started

```
Sub try_me()
Dim workbookPath As String
Dim output_filename As String

'getting your active workbook path
workbookPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path 

'pre-defined output filename
output_filename = "my_other_worksheet" 

'Copy your current active workbook to the new wb
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy

'save the workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=x & "\" & y & ".xls"
End Sub
```

Credit to Smitty here:
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/139831-create-empty-workbook-visual-basic-applications.html

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. I solved it by creating the file. Most probably copying can be done to existing file. Add code to create the file before copying to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is doubtful that a function can do this. I tried below code and it's working.

```
Public Sub EWbtn()

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\CRC Chart Extract.XLS"

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems you can not create a file directly in C drive through this. Either change the drive or create a folder inside C driver to save the file.

Comment: I made a few changes to the specs I need to meet. I just create a new workbook and copy over the sheets into it. Then leave the name so that the user will be prompted to save it as applicable at that time.

Comment: @Sbozhko that is the workaround to this, also please don't forget to accept the answer which helped.